# Will unisntalling django remove all the migrations and the changes I have made?

Tags: django

I did a very silly thing while I installed django. Instead of installing it within a python virtual  environment I installed it in within the system . I've been facing many problems since then and I was suggested to uninstall django and start afresh. Will unisntalling djnago remove all the migrations and the changes I've made within it ?

Comment: If you've made changes to the actual Django package, those would be lost. If you're wondering about your own app's code and migrations, those would stay the same.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the app's code and migrations ?